# How to save changes (which are made in editText) onto existing file in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My activity has some editText lines. When I open activity with different buttons, different data is read into this editText. User can then change or add text in editText, and when Save (Shrani) button is clicked I want these changes to be saved onto the existing file (the file from which the data was read).

I get the name of the file from which the data is read (and then should be saved onto), from another activity. The data is read so this part works fine. I just can't save changes.

```
public void save(String imeDatoteke1) {
    String nova = "\n";

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out =
                new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(imeDatoteke1, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        out.flush();
        out.write(predmet1.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(predmet2.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(predmet3.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(predmet4.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(predmet5.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(predmet6.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(predmet7.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(predmet8.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(predmet9.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(predmet10.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(predmet11.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(ocena1.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(ocena2.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(ocena3.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(ocena4.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(ocena5.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(ocena6.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(ocena7.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(ocena8.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(ocena9.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(ocena10.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.write(ocena11.getText().toString());
        out.write(nova);
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Vsebina je shranjena v datoteko.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it would be better to use a database rather than a flat file, is there some reason you can't do that?

Comment: I thought it would be easier with flat file that database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that You didn't get any exceptions in `catch`, otherwise You'd paste them in Your question. 
So, make sure imeDatoteke1(which is Your filename) doesn't have any spaces in it. It is worth mentioning that files opened with [context.MODE_PRIVATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput) by openFileOutput() will be created at private application space (/data/data/your_app_name/files/filename - i'm not sure if that directory is readable by adb shell - which of course is accessible after enabling debugging in device settings).

```
public void save(String filename) {

    EditText[] somelist = {predmet1,predmet2,predmet3};
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(root + "/" + filename));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for (EditText ed : somelist){
            out.write(ed.getText().toString());
            out.write("\n");
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Katja app", Util.stackTraceWriter(e));
    }

}
```

might do the trick, provided You have required permissions `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` ([see list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)).  And perhaps [this part](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) of Android training might interest You.

Comment: I changed context.MODE_PRIVATE to Context.MODE_APPEND, but it still doesn't work.
Then I tried the other suggestion, but I am getting this mistake: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied).

Comment: did You add mentioned permission to AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: it still doesn't work:( I remembered i forgot to mention something, maybe this is the problem..i have saved this txt files in directory ...\main\assets. Maybe I should save the files somwhere else?

From Android studio:
main/assets/
This is empty. You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of bytes using the AssetManager. For example, this is a good location for textures and game data.

Comment: Wait, You saved file in assets, and You want to update it with new values? This is not possible, asset directory is read only. You can read values from this file, but it can never be updated. You might want to keep Your data in other proposed by Google places: Shared Preferences, Database, Internal/External File (I might have missed few possibilities too.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am quite new in this Android Studio, so I make some mistakes. But now it all works fine :)